# How to repair broken Spotify on Mac

Tags: macos, freeze, spotify

I tried to develop a Spotify App on my Mac (OSX Lion). After a while Spotify stopped showing my app. It showed a blank screen instead, and the inspector showed an almost empty HTML DOM. The only elements were <html>, <head> and <body>.

After a restart searching for spotify:app:[myApp] didn't even work anymore. Simply nothing happened after hitting 'enter'.

So I decided to reinstall Spotify. Now it won't even startup anymore. I get the login screen, but after logging in, the login screen disappears, and the Spotify process freezes. Sometimes even before I get to enter my password.

I tried uninstalling Spotify with AppCleaner and CleanMyMac, but somehow it keeps crashing.

How do I repair this??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I had to delete /Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/SpotifyRemotePlugin.bundle

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with programming so this'll be gone pretty fast IMO:

- Delete ~/Library/Caches/com.spotify.client
- Delete ~/Library/Application Support/Spotify
- Delete all copies of Spotify.app from your system (look in ~/Applications too, it gets auto-installed in there).

Download from spotify.com, enjoy!